# Minimal LAMP iptables setup

Tags: security, lamp, iptables

What rules are needed for an Ubuntu LAMP server only having minimum necessary ports open.

Comment: Exactly how minimal are we talking though?  Since MySQL and PHP can be communicated with directly internally (hence the first item which allows loopback/localhost communication), there's no need to have their ports open to the universe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Minimal*?  Depending on how minimal we're talking, this'd work (I'm including SSH as being needed in this though):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
```

---

If you want to add other ports or services to be internet facing, those ports can be opened with `iptables -I INPUT [numberOfRules] -p [protocol] --dport [port or port:range] -j ACCEPT`, where `[numberOfRules]` is the number of the rule which has the REJECT target, `[protocol]` is the protocol (TCP, UDP, etc.), and `[port or port:range]` is either a single port or a range of ports defined with `start:end`.  Using comma separation also seems to work there.

Comment: LIMITATIONS: This does not include rules to allow for pings under certain circumstances, nor does it allow for any other connections on other ports from the outside.

Comment: Thanks, this will do until I move the database to another server.

Comment: This will allow for outbound communication though, so if the DB moves to another server you wont need to open another port.  The `conntrack` item will allow for the communication with the external server though, because your server initiated the communication (`RELATED` to an initiated connection started by your server, and `ESTABLISHED` because its, well, established.)

Comment: ^ The above comment is not entirely correct, the ports on the external server that the DBs are going to reside on will need to be opened.

Comment: FOR EVERYONE: I have further expanded and explained this answer at my blog, and have thrown a link up in the answer.